# Flat File Source returned status value 2 and status text The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

in the destination database I have a decimal field (15,2) and in the source of the etl the field is in a csv file, automatically ssis recognizes it as DT_STR data type what I did was change it to DT_NUMERIC 18 0 in the advanced editor. but when I run I get the error mentioned in the title of this question. I appreciate your help

Comment: `(18,0)` is different from `(15,2)` - so you should ensure they're both the same type. (The `decimal(18,0)` type accomodates fixed-precision decimal numbers up to 18 digits in length, but **without any fractional digits**, while `decimal(15,2)` accomodates numbers up to 15 digits in length but allows up to 2 fractional digits (e.g. `1234567890123.45` - that's why the types are incompatible.

Comment: thanks for replying dai, i already tried configuring in the advanced editor DT_NUMERIC 15 2 in the external and in the output, however the same error follows. I had left it with 18 to increase the size due to the possible loss of data

Comment: Which "Flat file" wizard are you using? (The new one is awful...), so what happens if you use the old, old one under SSIS?

Comment: I am working with a version of visual and sql server 2012, the task is called: "Flat File Source"